# How to get a file from a url and then read it as if it were local?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, binary-data, urllib3

I have a jpg image that is stored at a url that I need to access and read the binary/byte data from.

I can get the file in Python by using:

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'link to jpg'

contents = http.request('GET' url)
```

Purely reading the data from this request with `contents.data` doesn't provide the correct binary but if I download the file and read it locally, I get the correct binary. But I cannot continue with reading the file contents as such:

```
with open(contents, "rb") as image:
     f = image.read()
```

Using the bytes from the request doesn't work either:

```
with open(contents.data, "rb") as image:
     f = image.read()
```

How can I treat the jpg from the url as if it were local so that I can read the binary correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The result obtained in f when file is read locally and the result of `contents.data` is exactly the same.

```
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://tinyjpg.com/images/social/website.jpg'

contents = http.request('GET', url)
with open('website.jpg', "rb") as image:
     f = image.read()

print(f==contents.data)
```

You can download the image from the link in the code and then run this code, you will receive output `True` which implies the data read from local image file is same as data read from website.